# Reverse engineering message calls from iOS app

Tags: objective-c, reverse-engineering

I am studying an iOS app which uses undocumented API calls to do some magic.

What process should I use to dump or review API calls that are being made inside the app?

The binary is an Objective C program compiled for the ARM architecture.

Comment: There's a great book that just got released on iOS reverse engineering that should have the answer to your questions within it. [Check it out here.](https://github.com/iosre/iOSAppReverseEngineering)

Comment: @doctorBroctor This looks great, thanks so much